# .net Identity 2.0 not returning roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I have used this tutorial http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ to get an intro to the .net identity membership platform...I got it up and running OK. However, I went to extend my roles and now after I authenticate, there are no roles being returned(only an empty array)...see below for code:

- IdentityConfig.cs

  ```
  public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
  {
      public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
         : base(store)
      {}
      public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
      IOwinContext context)
      {
           return new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<AuthContext>()));
      }
  }

  public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
  {
      public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> roleStore)
         : base(roleStore)
      {}

  public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
  {
      var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(
                  new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context.Get<AuthContext>()));
      return manager;
  }
  }
  ```
- Startup.cs

  ```
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
      ConfigureOAuth(app);
      HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();        
      WebApiConfig.Register(config);
      app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      app.UseWebApi(config);
  }

  public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
  {
      // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
      app.CreatePerOwinContext(AuthContext.Create);
      app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
      app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
      //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

      OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
      {
          AllowInsecureHttp = true,
          TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
          AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
          Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
          RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
      };

      // Token Generation
      app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
      app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

  }
  ```
- AuthRepository.cs

  ```
  private AuthContext _ctx;

  private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

  public AuthRepository()
  {
      _ctx = new AuthContext();
      _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_ctx));
  }

  public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserModel userModel)
  {
      ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
      {
          UserName = userModel.UserName
      };

      var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);

      return result;
  }

  public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindUser(string userName, string password)
  {
      ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

      return user;
  }

  public Client FindClient(string clientId)
  {
      var client = _ctx.Clients.Find(clientId);

      return client;
  }

  public async Task<bool> AddRefreshToken(RefreshToken token)
  {

      var existingToken = _ctx.RefreshTokens.Where(r => r.Subject == token.Subject && r.ClientId == token.ClientId).SingleOrDefault();

      if (existingToken != null)
      {
          var result = await RemoveRefreshToken(existingToken);
      }

      _ctx.RefreshTokens.Add(token);

      return await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
  }

  public async Task<bool> RemoveRefreshToken(string refreshTokenId)
  {
      var refreshToken = await _ctx.RefreshTokens.FindAsync(refreshTokenId);

      if (refreshToken != null)
      {
          _ctx.RefreshTokens.Remove(refreshToken);
          return await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
      }

      return false;
  }

  public async Task<bool> RemoveRefreshToken(RefreshToken refreshToken)
  {
      _ctx.RefreshTokens.Remove(refreshToken);
      return await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
  }

  public async Task<RefreshToken> FindRefreshToken(string refreshTokenId)
  {
      var refreshToken = await _ctx.RefreshTokens.FindAsync(refreshTokenId);

      return refreshToken;
  }

  public List<RefreshToken> GetAllRefreshTokens()
  {
      return _ctx.RefreshTokens.ToList();
  }

  public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindAsync(UserLoginInfo loginInfo)
  {
      ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(loginInfo);

      return user;
  }

  public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
  {
      var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);

      return result;
  }

  public async Task<IdentityResult> AddLoginAsync(string userId, UserLoginInfo login)
  {
      var result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(userId, login);

      return result;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
      _ctx.Dispose();
      _userManager.Dispose();

  }
  ```
- ApplicationRole.cs

  ```
  public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
  {
       public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
       public ApplicationRole(string name)
           : base(name)
       {}
      public virtual string Module { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- ApplicationUser.cs

  ```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
       public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
       {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(
                 this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
       }

  }
  ```
- AuthContext.cs

  ```
  public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {
  new public DbSet<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }

  public AuthContext()
      : base("name=AuthDBConnectionString")
  {
    //  Database.SetInitializer<AuthContext>(null);
  }

  public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
  public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }

  static AuthContext()
  {
      // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
      // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
      Database.SetInitializer<AuthContext>(new AuthInitializer());
  }

  public static AuthContext Create()
  {
      return new AuthContext();
  }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      if (modelBuilder == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
      }

      // Keep this:
      modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

      // Change TUser to ApplicationUser everywhere else - 
      // IdentityUser and ApplicationUser essentially 'share' the AspNetUsers Table in the database:
      EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser> table =
          modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

      table.Property((ApplicationUser u) => u.UserName).IsRequired();

      // EF won't let us swap out IdentityUserRole for ApplicationUserRole here:
    //  modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<IdentityUserRole>((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);
      modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey((IdentityUserRole r) =>
          new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

      // Leave this alone:
      EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin> entityTypeConfiguration =
          modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey((IdentityUserLogin l) =>
              new
              {
                  UserId = l.UserId,
                  LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider,
                  ProviderKey
                      = l.ProviderKey
              }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");


      EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim> table1 =
          modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");



      // Add this, so that IdentityRole can share a table with ApplicationRole:
      modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

      // Change these from IdentityRole to ApplicationRole:
      EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole> entityTypeConfiguration1 =
          modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

      entityTypeConfiguration1.Property((ApplicationRole r) => r.Name).IsRequired();
  }
  ```
- In the lines below, if I change ApplicationRole to IdentityRole, then it seems to pull the roles back OK, but I need to add a 'Module' property found in ApplicationRole.cs above

  ```
          // Change these from IdentityRole to ApplicationRole:
      EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole> entityTypeConfiguration1 =
          modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

      entityTypeConfiguration1.Property((ApplicationRole r) => r.Name).IsRequired();
  ```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here...any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove these lines

```
    // Change these from IdentityRole to ApplicationRole:
//EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole> entityTypeConfiguration1 =
   // modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

//entityTypeConfiguration1.Property((ApplicationRole r) => r.Name).IsRequired();
```

Then in its place add

```
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

You will still get your tables as AspNetRoles and AspNetUsers using ApplicationRole since it is inherited from IdentityRole